# Mysql Database Backup from Remote System

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get database backup from remote system, please anyone help me to get backup from remote system. Here is the query which I executed, but its giving error.

```
mysqldump --host <host or IP address> -P <port Number> -u <username> -p<password> databaseName > c.sql;
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

remove ; from your syntax and execute below command-

```
mysqldump -h<IP_address> -u <username> -p<password> databaseName > backup.sql
```

If you want to take backup in your working directory else give a path. I have removed port option here as assuming that it will be running on default port 3306 else add in command.

Make sure your user should have permission on db server.